# How do I create a text link with a drop down menu in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried,

```
<div class = "btn-group" style="display:inline;">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Rate
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that the text link has a gradient around it which I don't like. How can I disable the gradient using CSS or is there some elegant way to do this? For some reason, copying this in jsfiddle doesn't work.

Comment: this code doesn't work as you described, not even with bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js. But to change background property. just use `background: none;` or `background: transparent;`

Comment: I can only see the background gradient after the button is clicked @warkentien2 So what should my CSS selector be?

Comment: considering the button you're referring to is the one with "Rate". use 
`a.dropdown-toggle:active { ... }` (should do the trick). you might also want to experiment with :hover and :focus http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Nope man.. background: none; or background: transparent; both didn't work..

Comment: Try to make an example (codepen is simpler to use frameworks). It's kinda hard to even imagine the problem. or at least post a print-screen of the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can make background-color of link to be transparent.

/* hide menu link background color */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

```css
/* hide menu link background color */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```